# Back button not triggering JS on Chrome

Tags: javascript, back, onunload

I have a horizontal scrolling website that you drag by clicking and dragging with the cursor. On load the page should load in the middle of the scroll and you can drag it left and right.

It works when you refresh but if you go to another page and press back the "scroll the middle onLoad" JS doesn't work and neither does the click and drag JS.

Attempted to add unload handlers with no success. Any ideas?

```js
// reload page to trigger JS after pressing back button
// firefox
function UnloadHandler() { window.removeEventListener('unload', UnloadHandler, false); }
window.addEventListener('unload', UnloadHandler, false);

//safari
window.addEventListener('pageshow', function (event) {
    if (event.persisted) {
        window.location.reload() 
    }
}, false);


// scroll to middle onLoad (horizontal, vertical)
document.querySelector('.home-container').scrollLeft = (document.querySelector('.home-container').scrollWidth - document.querySelector('.home-container').clientWidth) / 2


// enable click and drag

const slider = document.querySelector('.home-container');
let mouseDown = false;
let startX, scrollLeft;

let startDragging = function (e) {
  mouseDown = true;
  startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
};
let stopDragging = function (event) {
  mouseDown = false;
};

slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(!mouseDown) { return; }
  const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  const scroll = x - startX;
  slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - scroll;
});

// Add the event listeners
slider.addEventListener('mousedown', startDragging, false);
slider.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDragging, false);
slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', stopDragging, false);
```

Comment: It is giving me a null error

Comment: Try replacing `document.querySelector('.home-container').scrollWidth` with `document.querySelector('.home-container')?.scrollWidth`. So it check if it contains scrollWidth or not and wont throw error

Comment: You may be getting bitten by the back-forward cache. In which case, your page isn't actually being loaded again, it's just getting _shown_ again. In essence, as if you had only switched tabs, not left the page.

Comment: Agreed Darryl, that's why I tried the unload handler but that didn't work. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error I got when running it in latest chrome in windows 11:

```
{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollWidth')",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 26,
  "colno": 98
}
```

I think the error comes from this line:

```
document.querySelector('.home-container').scrollLeft = (document.querySelector('.home-container').scrollWidth - document.querySelector('.home-container').clientWidth) / 2
```

specifically from this part:

```
document.querySelector('.home-container').scrollWidth
```

I believe that the `querySelector` did not find an element of that description in the HTML, and so returned `null`. Therefore, when you try to take its `scrollWidth`, you get an error.

Comment: Aware of this error, but this part of the code does what it needs to do when the page loads. The issue the back button not loading the JS not this error

Comment: It probably doesn't, it is why I am getting the error. The code afterwardsdoes not run